# Can jinns move objects from your house?

Tags: jinn

Can jinns take things from your house, even insignificant things that you don't want just to cause confusion? If they wanted to misguide people could they move images/idols?

Comment: Islam is not teaching us much about Jinns and their actions. as the qur'an and Muhammad were sent to humans in first place. Nevertheless the qur'an supports the possibility that Jinns maybe able to move objects in the story of the prophet Sulayman () and the queen from Sheba.

Comment: Is this authentic? https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uTUTCrzHmLEC&pg=PT139&lpg=PT139&dq=Jinn+inside+idol+authentic+narration&source=bl&ots=bMAJMKKduP&sig=ACfU3U2HpWuivr2-ZuacY3FoAKWwiOrySw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi978LQzczqAhWMiFwKHcBaC1gQ6AEwC3oECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=Jinn%20inside%20idol%20authentic%20narration&f=false

Answer (score 2):

It has been prescribed in Islamic mythology that the genie can in fact move things. They call this Genie, the Ifreet. While from my studies the a-hadith and Quran do not mention this specifically, it has been suggested by some that the jinn has the power to move things.

Consider the jinn or genie of Solomon, who as a prophet commanded the moving of the throne from one location to the next via the genie. This though, is in the Quran.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed they can do a lot than just moving things in a house. There is not much in Quran about Jinns doing such things but if you go through the story of Hazrat Sulaeman (A.S) then you may clearly get all your answers.

Also, thousands of people have witnessed such stuff from time to time, and I firmly people in it because I have too seen a lot of these things.

Answer (score -2):

Not possible.

It has been prescribed that the Genie is hidden. The power of the Genie is hidden. We know they do exist with special powers but such tales are just folklore made by the magician to remove you from the prayer.

Comment: I'm sure you don't know what you are saying and simply because you do not have knowledge of that. Kindly reach the story of Hazrat Sulaeman (A.S) in the Quran and Hadiths.

Comment: If we can’t see them then they can’t do anything ? How does this make sense. It’s in the Quran, they did everything Sulaiman a.s wanted them to do, part of it was moving objects and building... so they obviously can do it.